# How to modify formatting AFTER counting a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that lists tasks assigned to agents. I need to count the number of tasks assigned to each agent, and return that number. I understand how to do the =COUNTIF(). What I would like to do is modify the formatting AFTER the equation has counted it.

Is this possible in Excel? I'm using Office 2013. All my research has returned "how to count all cells of a specific color". This is certainly an option. I've considered assigning a color to each relevant agent, then counting those cells that are assigned each color, but since I'm handling over 350,000 tasks, I want to verify they have been counted properly and this feels a lot like a detour of sorts to get to the end.

Thanks in advance for all your help and suggestions!

Comment: You can do this in VBA. It should be pretty simple if you spend a little time looking it up.

Comment: Thank you Justin. Sorry for the long response time. Unfortunately, my administrators have disabled VBA, and the pain and process of requesting a developer environment isn't worth the issue.